# How to convert a pytorch boolean tensor to a tensor with specified integers?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

How to convert a boolean torch tensor:

```
>>> t=torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.bool)
tensor([False,  True, False,  True])
```

to a tensor containing an integer `a` for True and `b` for False?

desired result:

```
tensor([b, a, b, a])
```

Answer (score 1):

With mask indexing:

```
mm = torch.tensor([False,  True, False,  True])
oo = torch.ones([4])
oo[mm] = 42
oo

tensor([ 1., 42.,  1., 42.])
```